# Avoid validating session against federated identity provider after login

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm using Azure B2C with a federated OpenID Connect identity provider. This idp is a bit special, since it does not retain a session, it rather provides a "fire and forget"-style login. The issue that I'm facing is that when the application validates the session in B2C, B2C will try to validate the session against the federated idp (as far as I can understand), which does not work and ends up prompting the user to log in again.

Is there a way to disable this type of validation? So that after login through the federated idp, only the session in b2c matters.

Comment: no sso then? What’s the point?

Comment: There is no sso from the federated idp, but I would like sso from b2c and only there. The federated idp is a login used for banking, so I guess they are a bit more strict than what's normal. Basically login into one bank should not mean that you can easily sso into another bank.